# Change default startup device in trigger.io

Tags: ios, xcode, trigger.io

Im amending an app using trigger.io, it is an iPad only app. When running the app It always starts up in an iPhone, changing it to iPad seems to break something. It also starts in the portrait orientation.

I have set:

```
"requirements": {
"ios": {
    "device_family": "ipad", 
    "minimum_version": "4.0"
}
```

But alas, still starts up in iPhone mode.

How can I get the simulator to always start up in the iPad in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: selecting the simulator family and version is possible since Trigger.io Forge v1.4.24: see `simulatorfamily` and `simulatorsdk` in http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/tools/local-config.html#available-forge-parameters

Previously, you had the run the simulator manually, from the command-line - that method preserved for completeness:

---

In a terminal, change to the app's directory and run:

```
.template/lib/ios-sim-xc4.3 launch development/ios/simulator-ios.app --sdk 5.0 --family ipad --stderr output.log
```

Here, you can change the `--sdk` and `--family` settings to use different versions and devices - run the command with no arguments to see available options.

If you get the simulator crashing on a segfault, make sure you use the `--stderr` argument to redirect output to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im using the web interface to run the simulator will this work when run from there?

Comment: > "Unknown docs page, if you followed a link it may have been removed, try searching below."

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble getting the Trigger `Device Type Id` setting working. Eg. You select `com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2, 7.1` and it always opens up an iPhone.

1. Open up XCode
2. Go to `Settings` then `Downloads`
3. Download the corresponding iOS Simulator version that matches what you selected in Trigger's `Device Type Id`.